# Workbench package dependency migration

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm developing a package (under workbench) which depends on another package (https://github.com/efficiently/authority-controller) for user role management. For this package to work, I need to run a migration initially. But however when I run the command `php artisan migrate --package=machuga/authority-l4`, it says `Nothing to migrate`.

I tried running `php artisan dump-autoload` from the root, and also `php artisan migrate --bench=machuga/authority-l4` but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add `Authority\AuthorityL4\AuthorityL4ServiceProvider` to your providers and run:

```
php artisan migrate --package=machuga/authority-l4
```

I think, `efficiently/authority-controller` depends on `machuga/authority`, but doesn't call the provider.